# not all nameservers are looked up

Tags: linux-mint, dns, resolv.conf

So I have multiple nameservers in my `/etc/resolv.conf`, but regarding the order in which they appear, I am able or not to resolve my corporate VPN hostnames: when VPN's DNS precedes my local one, **I am** able to resolve corporate hosts. When my local nameserver is the first one, **I am not** able to resolve corporate hosts.

I don't think it's the intened behaviour, since all nameservers must be tested, before throwing at me `NXDOMAIN`?

How would I make all nameservers active (not returning at first fail), so that order doesn't matter?

Comment: Nameservers are queries in order. If the first nameserver (which did not time out) returns `NXDOMAIN` resolving stops. This is documented in [`man resolv.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html). If you are using systemd-resolvd, things are [bit different](http://edgeofsanity.net/rant/2017/12/20/systemd-resolved-is-broken.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In DNS, the NXDOMAIN message is not exactly a failure. It is, or at least is supposed to be, perfectly valid information that the domain you asked for does not exist. Errors would be something like "I don't know" or "I'm not allowed to tell you" or "[dead silence until timeout]".

In `/etc/resolv.conf`, the expectation is that *all the configured nameservers are equal.* That is, they are supposed to all have the same access to DNS information: they all should be able to resolve any name you might need resolved.

If this is not true, then traditional Unix-style `/etc/resolv.conf` will be insufficient. Many have tried to achieve what you seek by tweaking the order of DNS servers in the file, but all have failed: **it just does not work that way.**

Instead, you'll typically need to set up a DNS resolver/cache/proxy that can be configured with some rules like "if the name you need resolved belongs to one of *these* domains, then ask one of *these* servers; if the name is in *that* domain, then use *that* server; and for everything else, use *those* servers."

For example, you could set up `dnsmasq` and write something like this in `dnsmasq.conf`:

```
no-resolv
server=/corporate-domain.com.example/10.1.2.3
rev-server=10.1.0.0/16,10.1.2.3
server=/google.com/8.8.8.8
server=9.9.9.9
```

This would mean:

- ignore `/etc/resolv.conf` (to prevent loops)
- use nameserver 10.1.2.3 to resolve any names in `corporate-domain.com.example` domain and any reverse queries for IP addresses in 10.1.0.0/16 network
- use 8.8.8.8 to resolve any names in the `google.com` domain
- for all the rest, use 9.9.9.9.

Once you had `dnsmasq` configured like this, you would then configure `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver 127.0.0.1` only, to redirect all local DNS requests to the local `dnsmasq`.

If your local nameserver is BIND, you can do the same using zone declarations of `type forward`:

```
zone "corporate-domain.com.example" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 10.1.2.3; };
};

zone "1.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 10.1.2.3; };
}; 

zone "google.com" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; }; 
};

options {
    forwarders { 9.9.9.9; };
    forward only;
};
```

This achieves the exact same results as the `dnsmasq` configuration above, but BIND configuration syntax is a bit more verbose.

Comment: Good explanation..+1. TDLR DNS behaves as it is expected, as not as the OP imagines it work. Small consolation to the OP, many do the common mistaking of making up stuff dreaming that DNS queries will trickle down the path of all resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative of trying to change DNS order or similar approaches:

If you controlling the VPN, instead of letting the client decide which DNS server to talk to (sort of), you can instead intercept DNS requests in port 53/UDP and port 53/TCP and redirect those requests to a DNS server of your choice.

In that way, when inside the VPN, you can force the clients to talk to a DNS server that is able to resolve the corporate hosts.

Case in point: I used to administer a couple of VPN servers with around 400 hundred BYOD VPN users that used their personal computers and phones.

As our country engages in censorship at the DNS level, many insert manually 8.8.8.8 as their DNS preferred servers.

Typically, the symptoms of those users were that they were not able to open corporate private addresses.

I had a couple choices:

- either helpdesk would take out the 8.8.8.8 address, and the users would insert them either willing or absently minded when they wanted to visit a blacklisted address, and we would be back to square 0;
- OR I could intercept DNS calls in the VPN no matter what the DNS addresses they were talking too, and redirect the DNS queries to the corporate DNS servers addresses.